# TCPDF cant able to read data from xlsx format?

Tags: php, tcpdf

If i used to read data from xls files its working, but when i used to .xlsx file for the PDF library cant able to read the content from the excel file.

any one can tell me solution for this.

Error:

```
The filename includes/user-uploads/apx4-899450-1365758229.xlsx is not readable
```

if i used to read a xls file its working fine. so the the URL in right.